# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'KeyCode'

Tags: python, typeerror

#### Code

```
 import socket
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
    import logging
    
    def on_press(key):
        logging.info(str(key))
        #print(str(key))
        """dosya = open("keys.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
        dosya.write(str(key))"""
        client = socket.socket()  # bir socket nesnesi oluşturuyoruz
        host = "localhost"  # bağlanacağımız adres
    
        port = 9000  # bağlanacağımız kapı
        client.connect((host, port))  # bağlantı yapılıyor
        print("Bağlantı yapıldı")
        client.send(key) # mesaj gönderiyoruz
    
        mesaj = client.recv(1024)  # geri gelen mesajı okuyoruz
        print(mesaj)
    
        """client.close()"""  # bağlantıyı kapatıyoruz
        with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

#### TypeError

and got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProject\pythonProject\venv\deneme.py", line 16, in on_press
    client.send(key) # mesaj gönderiyoruz
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'KeyCode'
```

Comment: What do you get when you print(str(key)) and just print(key)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question* that explains the problem in context - you ran some code and got an error; now what? What is the code *supposed to do*? *Where* does the error occur? *Why* do you need our help to solve the problem - *specifically what do you not understand* about the error? Did you try to [diagnose the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? What happened? Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146.

Comment: Also, did you try reading documentation, and checking the *type* of values (since the error message says there is a `TypeError`)? What is the type of `key`? What type of thing should be used for `client.send`? After reading the documentation, do you understand why? After understanding these things, what is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the `key` before you send it:

```
client.send(key.encode())
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes)

`encode()` returns a bytes representation of the Unicode string, encoded in the requested encoding if specified. The default encoding is `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Debugging

Read Eric Lippert's article ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get tips for debugging.

As you already did with logging and out-commented line:

```
        logging.info(str(key))
        #print(str(key))
```

Add a print-statement before sending to see the `key`.

```
print("Bağlantı yapıldı")
print(str(key))  # debug print the key before sending
client.send(key) # mesaj gönderiyoruz
```

#### Think about format of your payload when sending

Think of **how the key should be transmitted** over TCP sockets, in which format (binary, text, JSON).

#### From the docs

Maybe the example from official docs [*Monitoring the Keybord*](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) can inspire you

- which attributes to use from `key` for sending
- how to catch an `AttributeError`

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))
```

See also about the [`on_press`](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Listener) and its possible parameter types:

> It will be called with the argument (key), where key is a [`KeyCode`](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.KeyCode), a [`Key`](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key) or `None` if the key is unknown.